# Do we really need a "Sign Out" option for iPad native app?

Tags: ipad

I always quit (minimize) the app and jump to another app in my ipad. I don't use the sign out/log out option in any app.

I am curious if all the iPad users are like me. So, do we need "sign out" option in ipad app?

Comment: I log out of facebook on iPad, so my wife can use it. Some of us share an iPad, so the ability to log out is key.

Comment: It depends on what the app does.

Comment: Sign-out would just take you to a logged-out state within the current app. For example in a banking application you would sign-out, but still keep the application open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people share their iPad/tablets with their kids, significant other, ect, or even have multiple accounts depending on the service. For games this is less common, but for stuff like Facebook or Dropbox it's pretty important to be able to sign out.

However, it's not usually necessary to make the sign out option on the front page of the app; hide it under a menu unless you have really good reason to assume signing in/out constantly is going to be done. For some reason many iPad games include a splash screen offering you to sign out before you can play the game. Unless it's a banking/ect app, it's usually quite harmless to hide Sign Out under a logical menu somewhere (*in* the app, not in the Settings app) so it's out of the way for all of the single-user devices out there, while leaving the option perfectly available.